# Reading a specific class in a webpage using python

Tags: python

I have a script which reads `data` from a webpage using `HTMLParser`:

```
import urllib
from HTMLParser import HTMLParser
import re


class get_HTML_Info(HTMLParser):
    def handle_data(self, data):
        print data


adib = urllib.urlopen('http://www.bulldoghax.com/secret/spinner')
htmlsource = adib.read()
adib.close()

parser = get_HTML_Info()
parser.feed(str(htmlsource))
```

I end up with two set of data like this:

```
bulldoghax

8530330882
```

In the terminal, I just want to extract only that number and set it to a string in python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Beautiful Soup for scraping data.

`pip install BeautifulSoup`

```
import urllib
from HTMLParser import HTMLParser
import re

adib = urllib.urlopen('http://www.bulldoghax.com/secret/spinner')

htmlsource = adib.read()

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(htmlsource)
for each_div in soup.findAll('div',{'class':'number'}):
    print each_div.text
```

Comment: Thank you!, that's perfect!, I just had to change `soup = BeautifulSoup(htmlsource)` to `soup = BeautifulSoup(htmlsource, "lxml")` because it gave me an error the first time i tried it

Comment: @himanshu_dua can you help me with writing a code which sends that number a cookie value for this website `http://www.bulldoghax.com/secret/codes`

Answer (score 1):

Simple, here:

```
n="".join(filter(str.isdigit, data))
```

It filters the string based on being a number or not, then joins it into a string.

Comment: Thank you, now it's only showing the numbers, is there anyway I can remove the '\n' new line  things, I just want the output to be that number